# Why are all my threads using the same lock?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

I recently came across this code snippet

```
class Counter2 implements Runnable{

    private int value = 0;

    
    private Integer lock = 0;

    

    public void increment(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        value++;
    }

    public void decrement(){
        value--;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            this.increment();
            System.out.println(String.format("%s incremented value, value = %s", Thread.currentThread().getName(), this.value));
            this.decrement();
            System.out.println(String.format("%s decremented value, value = %s", Thread.currentThread().getName(), this.value));
        }
    }
}
public class Part8_synchronized_keyword_1 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Counter2 counter = new Counter2();
        new Thread(counter,"Thread1").start();
        new Thread(counter,"Thread2").start();
        new Thread(counter,"Thread3").start();
        new Thread(counter,"Thread4").start();
        Counter2 counterB = new Counter2();
        new Thread(counterB, "ThreadB").start();

    }
}
```

I get the output as follows

```
Thread1 incremented value, value = 1
Thread1 decremented value, value = 0
ThreadB incremented value, value = 1
ThreadB decremented value, value = 0
Thread4 incremented value, value = 1
Thread4 decremented value, value = 0
Thread3 incremented value, value = 1
Thread3 decremented value, value = 0
Thread2 incremented value, value = 1
Thread2 decremented value, value = 0
```

Why is it that it seems that threadB is competing with thread1...4 for the same lock?.
Because from my understanding the lock object will be different for counterB and counter

Comment: Did you try running it several times? Each time the output shall be different.

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: The output shows the run mentods of all threads being executed completly only then the next thread executes. If counterB used a different lock then its outputs would be interleaved with the other outputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption that `counter` and `counterB` use different locks **is wrong**.

**Why**: because you declared your lock as

```
private Integer lock = 0;
```

and the JVM caches `Integer` objects for all values from -128 to 127.

Declare your lock as

```
private Object lock = new Object();
```

and only then will `counter` and `counterB` use different locks!

---

Note the important distinction here between object references and the referenced objects:

Both `counter` and `counterB` have a field `lock`, but these fields are not objects, they are merely references to some object.

For

```
private Integer lock = 0;
```

that referenced "some object" is the same for `counter` and `counterB` (because the Java Language Specification requires this for boxing of `int` values in the range -128 to 127) and synchronization happens on the object, not on the reference.

Excerpt from the [Java Language Specification, Boxing Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> If the value `p` being boxed is the result of evaluating a constant expression (§15.29) of type `boolean`, `byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, or `long`, and the result is `true`, `false`, a character in the range `'\u0000'` to `'\u007f'` inclusive, or an integer in the range `-128` to `127` inclusive, then let `a` and `b` be the results of any two boxing conversions of `p`. It is always the case that `a == b`.

Comment: Still wouldn't two separate objects for lock be cached for counter and counterB ?

Comment: @H-Bar: the point is that there is only one Integer with the value 0 for the whole jvm.

Comment: @H-Bar I've updated my answer with an explanation why `Integer lock = 0;` always results in the same `Integer` object.